# I would like to select the max field in a sql column but list the rest in order as well

Tags: sql

My sql table only has one column and it's "ID"

```
select MAX(id) from eve.db.dde
```

it only returns the 1 field (the highest)

How do i return all the fields in order from highest to lowest?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id FROM eve.db.dde ORDER BY ID DESC
```